# What's the best way to build a factory using NInject?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am pretty comfortable with dependency injection using NInject in MVC3. While working in an MVC3 application, I developed a custom Controller Creation Factory using NInject, so any controller that is created will have dependencies injected in it through this Controller Factory.

Now I am starting to develop a windows application, I want to use Application wide Dependency Injection. i.e. Every object must be created through NInject, so as to ease Unit Testing. Please guide me to ensure that every object created must be though the NInject Factory only.

For example, if on any windows form on `Button_Click` event I write:

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass()
```

and `TestClass` has any dependency on, say, `ITest` then it must be automatically resolved. I know I can use:

```
Ikernel kernel = new StandardKenel()
//AddBinding()
TestClass testClass = kenel.get<TestClass>();
```

But I find it tedious to do this every time I want to create an object. It also the forces developer to create the object in a particular way. Can it be made better?

Can I have a central repository for object creation and then every object creation will automatically use that repository?

Comment: Hi Pravin Patil: great question. I made a minor change to your title to make it clearer about what you're asking; feel free to modify if I missed the mark.

Comment: @MarkTrapp : Thank for the suitable title. I missed that tagline...

Comment: As minor side note, the project is spelt "Ninject", not "NInject". While it might be that it has been En-Inject, they play on nin-ja theme quite a bit nowadays. :) Cf. http://www.ninject.org/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For client applications, it's often best to adapt a pattern like MVP (or MVVM) and use data-binding from the form to the underlying ViewModel or Presenter.

For the ViewModels, you can inject the required dependencies using standard Constructor Injection.

In your application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) you can wire up the [entire object graph](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx) for your application. You don't need to use a DI Container (such as Ninject) for this, but you can.

Answer (score 8):

Windows Forms applications typically have a point of entry that looks like this:

```
    // Program.cs
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

If you make this point in code your *composition root*, you can vastly reduce the number of places where you have code explicitly invoking Ninject as if it were a Service Locator.

```
    // Program.cs
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var kernel = InitializeNinjectKernel();
        Application.Run(kernel.Get<MainForm>());
    }
```

From this point, you inject all your dependencies via constructor injection.

```
public MainForm(TestClass testClass) {
    _testClass = testClass;
}
```

If your "dependency" is something you need to be able to produce multiple times, then what you really need is a factory:

```
public MainForm(IFactory<TestClass> testClassFactory) {
    _testClassFactory = testClassFactory;
}

...
var testClass = _testClassFactory.Get();
```

You can implement the IFactory interface this way to avoid having to create a ton of one-off implementations:

```
public class InjectionFactory<T> : IFactory<T>, IObjectFactory<T>, IDependencyInjector<T>
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    private readonly IParameter[] _contextParameters;

    public InjectionFactory(IContext injectionContext)
    {
        _contextParameters = injectionContext.Parameters
            .Where(p => p.ShouldInherit).ToArray();
        _kernel = injectionContext.Kernel;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return _kernel.Get<T>(_contextParameters.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                string.Format("An error occurred while attempting to instantiate an object of type <{0}>",
                typeof(T)));
        }
    }

...
Bind(typeof (IFactory<>)).To(typeof (InjectionFactory<>));
Bind(typeof (IContext)).ToMethod(c => c.Request.ParentContext);
```

Comment: Please, do you have the full implementation for this factory?

Comment: @ColourBlend: No, but if you get rid of the other interfaces that I had `InjectionFactory<T>` implementing, then the code provided should work just fine. Is there something in particular that you're having issues with?

Comment: I already implemented it, i just want to know if there were other interesting stuff within the class.

Comment: @Tebo: I just had it implementing a couple of other DI-related interfaces, like a factory that you could pass a `Type` to, but which would guarantee that the objects it hydrated for that `Type` implement or extend a given generic type. Nothing too special.

Answer (score 4):

I always write an Adapter wrapper for any IoC Container, which looks like this:

```cs
public static class Ioc
{
    public static IIocContainer Container { get; set; }
}

public interface IIocContainer 
{
    object Get(Type type);
    T Get<T>();
    T Get<T>(string name, string value);
    void Inject(object item);
    T TryGet<T>();
}
```

For Ninject, specifically, the concrete Adapter class looks like this:

```cs
public class NinjectIocContainer : IIocContainer
{
    public readonly IKernel Kernel;
    public NinjectIocContainer(params INinjectModule[] modules) 
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
        new AutoWirePropertyHeuristic(Kernel);
    }

    private NinjectIocContainer()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();
        Kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        new AutoWirePropertyHeuristic(Kernel);
    }

    public object Get(Type type)
    {
        try
        {
            return Kernel.Get(type);
        }
        catch (ActivationException exception)
        {
            throw new TypeNotResolvedException(exception);
        }              
    }

    public T TryGet<T>()
    {
        return Kernel.TryGet<T>();
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            return Kernel.Get<T>();
        }
        catch (ActivationException exception)
        {
            throw new TypeNotResolvedException(exception);
        }           
    }

    public T Get<T>(string name, string value)
    {
        var result = Kernel.TryGet<T>(metadata => metadata.Has(name) &&
                     (string.Equals(metadata.Get<string>(name), value,
                                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

        if (Equals(result, default(T))) throw new TypeNotResolvedException(null);
            return result;
    }

    public void Inject(object item)
    {
        Kernel.Inject(item);
    }
}
```

The primary reason for doing this is to abstract out the IoC framework, so I can replace it at any time -- given that the difference between frameworks is generally in configuration rather than in usage.

But, as a bonus, things also become a lot easier for using the IoC framework inside other frameworks that don't inherantly support it. For WinForms, for example, it is two steps:

In your Main method, simply instantiate a container before doing anything else.

```cs
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Ioc.Container = new NinjectIocContainer( /* include modules here */ );
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyStartupForm());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And then have a base Form, from which other forms derive, which calls Inject on itself.

```cs
public IocForm : Form
{
    public IocForm() : base()
    {
        Ioc.Container.Inject(this);
    }
}
```

This tells the auto-wiring heuristic to attempt to recursively inject all properties in the form which fit the rules set up in your modules.

Comment: Very nice solution..... I will give it a try.

Comment: That's a Service Locator, which is a spectacularly bad idea: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Comment: @MarkSeemann: A service locator is a bad idea, if you access it from everywhere, instead of letting it wire up your top level objects as far down as it can. Read Mark's own comment, a little way down the page: "In such cases you really have no recourse but to move the Composition Root into each object (e.g. Page) and let your DI Container wire up your dependencies from there. This may look like the Service Locator anti-pattern, but it isn't because you still keep container usage at an absolute minimum." (Edit: Wait, you ARE Mark! So what is the difference?)

Comment: The difference is that you can still shield the rest of your code base from the Composer, instead of making a Singleton Service Locator available to any class.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I guess. But then you run into problems later if you want to inject into Attributes or something else high-level. I'd rather have it available everywhere and trust my developers to not misuse it. I do agree with your article where you're offering an API to someone else though.

Comment: @pdr: In my experience, if you're attempting to inject services into things like attribute classes, you're not separating concerns properly. There are cases where the framework you're using makes it practically impossible to use proper dependency injection, and sometimes we're forced to use a service locator, but I'd definitely try to take true DI as far as possible before reverting to this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Good use of Dependency Injection usually relies on seperating the code which creates objects and the actual business logic. In other words, I would *not want* my team to frequently use `new` and create an instance of a class that way. Once it is done, there is no way to easily swap out that created type for another, since you have already specified the concrete type.

So there are two ways to go about fixing this:

1. Inject the instances that a class will need. In your example, inject a `TestClass` into your Windows Form so that it already has an instance when it needs it. When Ninject instantiates your form, it automatically creates the dependency.
2. In cases where you really *don't* want to create an instance until you need it, you can inject a factory into the business logic. For example, you can inject an `IKernel` into your Windows Form, and then use that to instantiate `TestClass`. Depending on your style, there are other ways to accomplish this as well (injecting a factory class, factory delegate, etc).

Doing this makes it easy to swap out both the concrete type of TestClass, as well as modify the actual construction of the test class, without actually modifying the code which *uses* the test class.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Ninject, but the standard way of creating stuff when you are using a IoC is to do so via a `Func<T>` where `T` is the type of object you want to create. So if object `T1` needs to create objects of type `T2` then the constructor of `T1` must have parameter of type `Func<T1>` which is then stored as a field / property of `T2`. Now when you want to create objects of type `T2` in `T1` you invoke the `Func`.

This totally decouples you from your IoC framework and is the right way to code in an IoC mindset.

The downside to doing this is that it can get annoying when you need to manually wire `Func`s or example when your creator requires some parameter, so the IoC cannot autowire the `Func` for you.

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes